# Reducing similar code into a single execution

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dry

I have some if statements where I run a foreach in every if-statement for different DbSets.
I see that, I'm just repeating myself over and over again. Does anyone know how to reduce code below into a single execute for all my defined if-statements?

DbSets defined through 'configContext' all have different types. So does the Config.[collection].

Types are listed below:

For configContext.[collection]:

- (KEY 1) '**configContext!.Clients**' has actual type: Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Entities.Client
- (KEY 2) '**configContext!.IdentityResources**' has actual type: Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Entities.IdentityResource
- (KEY 3) '**configContext!.ApiScopes**' has actual type: Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Entities.ApiScope
- (KEY 4) '**configContext!.ApiResources**' has actual type: Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Entities.ApiResource

For Config.[collection], other types are being used

- (VALUE OF KEY 1) '**Config.Clients**' has actual type: Duende.IdentityServer.Models.Client
- (VALUE OF KEY 2) '**Config.IdentityResources**' has actual type: Duende.IdentityServer.Models.IdentityResource
- (VALUE OF KEY 3) '**Config.ApiScopes**' has actual type: Duende.IdentityServer.Models.ApiScope
- (VALUE OF KEY 4) '**Config.ApiResources**' has actual type: Duende.IdentityServer.Models.ApiResource

**NOTE**

Although I have different types each key can be mapped from model to entity or from entity to model. So keys and values have 1:1 relationship. Difference between keys and values is that Keys are Database Entities and Values are Models

```
    // Add OAuth2 and OpenID Connect clients to database
            if (configContext!.Clients.Any() == false)
            {
                foreach (Client client in Config.Clients)
                {
                    configContext.Clients.Add(client.ToEntity());
                }
                configContext.SaveChanges();
            }

            // Add facts about a user to database (like email, user Id, etc.)
            if (configContext.IdentityResources.Any() == false)
            {
                foreach (IdentityResource resource in Config.IdentityResources)
                {
                    configContext.IdentityResources.Add(resource.ToEntity());
                }
                configContext.SaveChanges();
            }

            // Add API access scopes to database
            if (configContext.ApiScopes.Any() == false)
            {
                foreach (ApiScope apiAccess in Config.ApiScopes)
                {
                    configContext.ApiScopes.Add(apiAccess.ToEntity());
                }
                configContext.SaveChanges();
            }

            // Add APIs needed to be protected to database
            if (configContext.ApiResources.Any() == false)
            {
                foreach (ApiResource api in Config.ApiResources)
                {
                    configContext.ApiResources.Add(api.ToEntity());
                }
                configContext.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Comment: The duplication isn't really that bad. You can reduce it some by replacing the `foreach` with `configContext.Clients.AddRange(Config.Clients.Select(c => c.ToEntity()));`

Answer (score 1):

you could add a method like this and call it for each collection of entities you want to add if there are not already any.

```
private void AddIfNotExists<TEntity>(DbContext context, IEnumerable<TEntity> listToAdd)
  where TEntity : class
{
  if (!context.Set<TEntity>().Any())
  {
    foreach(var item in listToAdd)
    {
      context.Add<TEntity>(item);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but the thing is I have not a single TEntity but two.So TEntity is needed for the context, but the second let's say TOther is needed for the IEnumerable.If I use your example, then outside the AddIfNotExists I need to pass in various types for TEntity.I have a List<Type> that consists of typeof(TypeX) and typeof(TypeY). Through a foreach loop I try to use something like: foreach(type in types) {AddIfNotExists<type, Client>(configContext, Config.Clients);}.This example will not work, since I use a variable to define the type which is not allowed.How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It's hard to follow why this answer doesn't help. It looks like there are significant details missing from the question that are only available in this comment. It's important to have the whole question in the question, not part of it in the question and more details in the comment.

Comment: I added the various types related to configContext and Config class. Hopefully, it is a bit more clear now.

Comment: @user20291437 the .ToEntity() method seems to be inherited by an interface/base class so you can write `IEnumerable<IEntityWrapper> listToAdd` and replace the IEntityWrapper with the real interface and down below change the add method to `context.Add<TEntity>(item.ToEntity())` sorry i don't know your library and can give an exact example. but i hope you get the idea.

Comment: Im using the following libraries:
Duende.IdentityServer and 
Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework